# Embed FPPF group scheme into smooth one

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, schemes

Let $A$ be a ring and $G$ be an affine commutative FPPF group scheme over $A$. Can we embed $G$ into a smooth group scheme over $A$?

Comment: I believe that this is open. Here is a similar question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22078/smooth-linear-algebraic-groups-over-the-dual-numbers

Comment: One positive result: Let $N$ be a finite flat group scheme over a noetherian scheme $S$. Locally for the Zariski topology on $S$, there exists a projective abelian scheme $A$ and an embedding of $N$ into $A$. Raynaud 1979.